# (Swift) Sharing on Facebook set initial text?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook

The code that I am using prepares a screenshot and opens the share window with the screenshot. However, the setInitialText does not seem to work. At least anything I enter in it is not appearing. The root does not state that it is depreciated.

```
let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen()

    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screen.bounds.size, false, 0);
        window.drawViewHierarchyInRect(window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        composeSheet.setInitialText("I just hit \(highscore) on Reflext Test! Can you beat me?")
        composeSheet.addImage(image)

        presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is now Facebook doesn't allow pre-filled text to be posted/shared. This link will provide you information about Facebook pre-filled text policy.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: Thanks! I usually just rely on getting my info on xcode comments. So does mean we can no longer send the link of our app too?

Comment: Links, images can be shared and posted but not pre-filled text. The link which I have shared has a video go through that video, it might be useful to you.